# I have error when update SQL from node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, backend

I use for-loop to update sql command.

like this

```
for(var i=count1; i < count2;i++){        
  Book.TimeStart = Times[I]
  console.log(Book.TimeStart)
  sql = sql + `UPDATE projectroom.Details SET BookingId = `+Book.BookingId+`, status = 'W' 
  WHERE RoomID = `+Book.RoomID+` 
  and dates = '`+Book.Dates+`'
  and TimeId = (Select TimeId from projectroom.Timeslot where TimeStart = '`+Book.TimeStart+`'); \n`
}
```

if data from JSON get in the loop only once. it's not error.

but it gets in the loop more than one. it's error. (I config with mySQL)

this is my error:

```
code: 'ER_PARSE_ERROR',
  errno: 1064,
  sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE projectroom.Details
SET BookingId = 193, status = 'W' WHERE RoomID = 101 ' at line 2",
  sqlState: '42000',
  index: 0,
  sql: "UPDATE projectroom.Details SET BookingId = 193, status = 'W' WHERE RoomID = 101 and dates = '2020-03-16'and TimeId = (Select TimeId from projectroom.Timeslot where TimeStart = '09:00:00'); \n" +
    "UPDATE projectroom.Details SET BookingId = 193, status = 'W' WHERE RoomID = 101 and dates = '2020-03-16'and TimeId = (Select TimeId from projectroom.Timeslot where TimeStart = '09:30:00'); \n" +
    "UPDATE projectroom.Details SET BookingId = 193, status = 'W' WHERE RoomID = 101 and dates = '2020-03-16'and TimeId = (Select TimeId from projectroom.Timeslot where TimeStart = '10:00:00'); \n"
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag MySQL questions as SQL Server. Microsoft doesn't have anything to do with that product.

Comment: As about your question, are you positively sure that your Node.js database layer supports multiple statements per call?

Comment: when I add multiple statements in nodejs and it works. thank you so much

Answer (score -1):

thats works for me :

```
router.put('/:id', (req, res)=>{

        console.log(req.body)
        console.log(req.params)
        console.log(req.session)

        let sql = `UPDATE expend
                SET ?
                WHERE expen_id = ?`

        let params = [
                req.body, 
                req.params.id
                ];

        conexion.query(sql, params, function(err,result,fields){

                let respuesta;

                if (err){
                        respuesta={
                                status: 'error',
                                message: 'Error al modificar la receta',
                                err: err
                        }       
                }
                else{
                        respuesta= {
                                        status: 'ok',
                                        message: 'la respuesta se agregó',
                                  }
                }
                res.json(respuesta);
        })

})
```

Comment: I don't see how this relates to the problem described in the question. If it actually solves the problem then providing an explanation would be more helpful than a game of spot-the-difference.